# Error when connecting HDMI Monitor

Tags: display, laptop, hdmi

Yesterday I got a new monitor which I connected with HDMI to my laptop. Everything worked just fine. When I plug in my HDMI cable today, the laptop screen shuts off and displays the attached photo every 2-3 seconds which is also displayed every 2-3 seconds on the monitor. 
Plugging the HDMI cable back out doesn't solve the problem for the laptop screen either.

EDIT:

```
lspci -vvv|grep -A 11 'VGA '
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 0647
Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Latency: 0
Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 28
Region 0: Memory at b3000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
Region 2: Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
Region 4: I/O ports at 3000 [size=64]
Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] GeForce 710M
Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Latency: 0
Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 35
Region 0: Memory at b2000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
Region 1: Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
Region 3: Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
Region 5: I/O ports at 2000 [size=128]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

Comment: What is your graphic card and the driver you are using ? Edit your post to add output of `lspci -vvv|grep -A 11 'VGA '`

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem: Nvidia driver doesn't work with the two monitors.